# Restrict particular characters in HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm sure this is a simple question, that you'll be annoyed at and answer with a simple link.

My issue is that I can't find what I'm looking for, because I don't understand enough about PHP/MySQL/HTML forms to come up with a particularly Google-able query.

I want to restrict the character set for an email field in a manner like:

`*@*.tld`

or

`*@domain.tld`

if that makes sense?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You mean `@domain.tld` ?

Comment: Right, so I'd restrict either to a specific domain(s), or specific tld(s).

Comment: So google for splitting domain names and how to replace with whatever you think is "correct"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check domain in your email you can try with this one

```
$arr = explode('@', $email_address); 
if ($arr[1] == 'domain.tld') 
{ // Then it's correct }
```

Or if you want to validate email address, You can validate your email address after form submission with `filter_var()` in server side

```
<?php
$email_a = 'joe@example.com';
$email_b = 'bogus';

if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_a) email address is considered valid.";
}
if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_b) email address is considered valid.";
}
?>
```

Have a look here for details:
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: Thanks, but that only confirms it *is* an email address, any email address. Further to that, I'd like to confirm it is of a desired domain or tld. Can I use the regexp ID for that?

Comment: Ah, got it, I think. Used `if(filter_var($user, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, '/@domain.tld'))` - thanks!